# Nested For Loop - A problem with understanding the concept

Tags: python, nested-for-loop

Welcome

I generally understand the concept of loops and how they work. Yet, I have encountered one that I just cannot comprehend

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i, end="")
print()
```

This loop will display a list of numbers

> 1
>  22
>  333
>  4444
>  55555
>  666666
>  7777777
>  88888888
>  999999999

Which is exactly what i wanted... But i cannot understand why does it print the same numbers in each line. If the "j" variable is printed the program act like i expectd it to work.

> 0
> 01
> 012
> 0123
> 01234
> 012345
> 0123456
> 01234567
> 012345678

Does anybody have any idea why that is?

Edit:

Thank you for the answers. I finally get it(and feel so stupid that I haven't before)

Comment: FYI: `range(10)` gives you the numbers `0` - `9`.  `range(0)` gives you nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same character is repeated because the second `for` loop is printing `i`, the value from the outer loop. If it was printing `j` it would look how you expect. The value of `i` only changes once the `j` loop finishes. An outer loop won't repeat until any inner loops are done.

If this wasn't obvious to you even after you printed `j`, then it seems like your knowledge of `for` loops is lacking something fundamental. You would greatly benefit from learning to use a debugger, which is critical day 1 knowledge for any software engineer.

Answer (score 1):

```
range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# your loop
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i, end="")
```

Let me break it down a little

```
range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# replacing 'i' with 'j'
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j, end="")
i = 0 #range(0)
nil 
i = 1
#in nested loop range(1) = [0]
0
i = 2
#range(2) = [0,1]
0 1
#range(3) = [0, 1, 2]
0 1 2
#range(4) = [0, 1, 2, 3]
0 1 2 3
#range(5) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
0 1 2 3 4
```

I hope it makes sense now